# How to get only today,7 days, one month and 1 year data from today in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, time, cakephp-3.0

How to get only today,7 days, one month and 1 year data from today in cakephp 3 ? any idea?

Controller code:
if($status == 1){

```
            $data = $this->Sites->find('all')->where(['user_id' => $uid]);
            $a = $data->toArray();
            $id = $a[0]['id'];
            $this->loadModel('Details');

            $details = $this->Details->find('all')->where(['site_id' => $id]);
            $tmp = $details->toArray();
            print_r($tmp);

        }
```

view code:

Form->create('Add',(['id' => 'frm'])); ?>
                    Form->input('status', array(
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'id' => 'mySelect',
                            'onchange' => 'myFunction()',
                            'empty' => 'View Details',
                            'options' => array('1'=>'1 Day','7'=>'7 Days', '30' => '1 Month', '365' => '1 Year')
                           )
                        );
                    ?>

Comment: Are you talking about a query call? The time class? We need more information.

Comment: in my controller i have the following query $details = $this->Details->find('all')->where(['site_id' => $id, 'downtime' => '2015-12-05']); and in my phpmyadmin i have a field of downtime and in view i have create a select list when i select the one day from the dropdown then i want to show only today results . But i don't know how to do this using query

Comment: Edit your question to include the form and controller code. That way we can see what you are working with.

Comment: <?= $this->Form->create('Add',(['id' => 'frm'])); ?>
     <?php 
     
      echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
       'type' => 'select',
       'id' => 'mySelect',
       'onchange' => 'myFunction()',
       'empty' => 'View Details',
       'options' => array('1'=>'1 Day','7'=>'7 Days', '30' => '1 Month', '365' => '1 Year')
         )
      );
     ?> I have apply on change event when form submit it goes through the controller and i want to generate the graph when i select the 1 day from dropdown i want to show the graph of only one day .Thanks

Comment: I just want to know the query to get the data of current day, 7 days ,1 month and 1 year ? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer you question, use the [CakePHP Time class](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html) or the [PHP DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

You could use the Time Class like this :

```
$now = Time::now();
$details = $this->Details->find('all')->where(['site_id' => $id, 'downtime' => $now]);
```

The above example would give Date and Time at the current call. You could instantiate an object with the Time class and passing in a string:

```
$today = new Time('today');
$seven_days_ago = new Time('7 days ago');
$one_month_ago = new Time('1 month ago');
```

Or you could actually do it through the class actions:

```
$today = Time::now();
$seven_days_ago = (Time::now())->subDays(7);
```

To answer your edited question, you would get the as needed and then pass them into the query builder:

```
$now = Time::now();
$seven_days_ago = new Time('7 days ago');

$details = $this->Details->find('all')->where(['site_id' => $id, function($exp) use($now, $seven_days_ago) {
    $exp->between('downtime', $seven_days_ago, $now);
}]);
```

Comment: I would recommend formatting the $now into just a date `$now->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd'); `